# Apache mod-rewrite - hidding PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm try to get my url rewrites to direct whenever .php is added to the end of the url, but essentially I get an error when I include the commented out part.

I can get the .php error to work on it's own, but not with all the other rules in place. in it's current form, it makes every page error.

All other parts are working.

The site is setup so any errors go to one page - error.php

```
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On

    ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
    ErrorDocument 301 /error.php
    ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
    ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
    ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
    ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
    ErrorDocument 500 /error.php


    ###### Send any requests for to error ######
    RewriteRule    ^index(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    error.php    [R=404,NC,L]

    ###### changing Validate URL ########
    RewriteRule    ^validate/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/*?$    validate.php?$1=$2&$3=$4    [NC,L]

    ###### Show 404 error page when any request ends with '.php'
            RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php(.?.*)$ error.php [R=404,NC,L]

    #       I also want to allow for anything that contains a get request here. but wanted to get the .php bit working first.



    ###### To remove the trailing slash ######
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
    RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `.php to 404` rule with this rule:

```
###### Show 404 error page when any request ends with '.php'

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[?\s/] [NC]
RewriteRule !^/?error\.php$ /error.php [R=404,L,NC]
```

Comment: only issue now is that it can seem to find my defined error page. I'm getting the same error as with the previous example. I'm wondering if I've indicated my `ErrorDocument 404 /error.php` incorrectly of in the wrong order?

Comment: I get a slightly different 'internal server error' when I include your second suggestion. `Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Comment: Thanks, It's 95% there, It redirects everything ending in .php to error now. The only issue is that ideally I'd like it to keep the typed url e.g. `ex.com/test.php` instead of displaying `ex.com/error/` Is that possible?

Comment: My rule won't change URL in browser. You should completely clear browser cache when testing this.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciated. That works nicely now. I didn't realise that headers and re-writes could be cached.

Comment: I made one change actually. I'm trying to hide the fact that I'm using php, so I've added in `[R=404]` your second line is now. `RewriteRule !^/?error\.php$ /error.php [R=404,L,NC]`. Without it was producing a 200 status.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below rule,

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ error.php [R=404,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! I get this when visiting any page like x.com/test. Commenting out this line brings it back to normal.


Not Found

**The requested URL /test.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**